# How to position bullet on top of tabular?

Tags: tables, itemize, resume, bullets

I currently have the following command defined:

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}
    {0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

and I use it between the following commands

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
```

For example, I have

```
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
  \resumeSubheading
    {Sample School}{City, Country}
    {Bachelor's degree}{2017 - 2021}
    {\scriptsize \textit{ \footnotesize{\newline{}       Coursework: Course One, Course Two, Course Three.}}}
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

which produces

[image]

As you can see, the bullet point comes in the middle of the first part. How can I change the command so that the bullet point is at the start of the item?

Comment: remove all the `\vspace` and use `\begin{tabular*}{...}[t]`

Comment: Thanks, the [t] part worked but removing the vspace made it look off in places, so I kept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\begin{tabular*}{...}[t]` to top align a `tabular`